# vertical scroll bar with some fixed pixel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one problem is that my HTMl body has a width of `1600px`.
I want vertical scroll bar up to `900px`.
When I zoom my images of `900px` then it scale but also gives vertical scrollbar more than `900px`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
   <div style="left:0px;  position: absolute; top:0px ; overflow:hidden ; min-height:800px; min-width:1000px; max-width:500px; max-height:800px ">
     <object  data="Map3.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="500" height="800" id="svgObj" style="background-color:#09C ; left:200px;  position: absolute; top:0px ; overflow:hidden ; "   >

        <param name="src" value="Map2.svg">

    </object>
    </div>
```